# Properties Class and Escape Characters

Tags: java, properties, bufferedreader

I used properties class to store a map into a file. 
But some characters are stores with a "\" added at the beginning.

Is there any way to print the actual content as it is without these escapes using Properties Class.

I am writing using properties class but reading using a BufferedReader . 
I could not understand which characters are escaped when written using Properties Class .

Is there any way to read data without these escapes using BufferedReader ?

For eg :

If the actual content is `abc:def:ghi`
When i assign this value to a property called name and store it in a file using properties class , it is stored as :

```
name=abc\:def\:ghi.
```

Now when i read this using BufferedReader , i get all the \ characters as well in the content.

The problem is i do not know what all characters are stored with an added \ character.

Comment: Can you please post a working example that demonstrates the issue? Also, why can't you use `Properties` to read too?

Comment: @BackSlash : Updated the question

Comment: You posted data; not a working example. You problem can be caused by various reasons; therefore it is essential that you provide **code**. Besides: typically ... when you are able to repro the problem with a few line of standalone code; you are almost there resolving the problem. So: try to understand what you code does; and try to do that without the "clutter" around.

Comment: If you use `Properties` to write the data, simply use `Properties` to read them back. If you want to convert `Properties` to a `String`, there are easier ways to achieve this. The output format and its escape sequences are no secret, just look into the documentation of the method you use to store.

Answer (score 2):

All special char are escaped by java.util.Properties. You can not provide it.

It will be done in [saveConvert](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Properties.java#Properties.saveConvert%28java.lang.String%2Cboolean%2Cboolean%29):

```
   /*
     * Converts unicodes to encoded &#92;uxxxx and escapes
     * special characters with a preceding slash
     */
    private String saveConvert(String theString,
                               boolean escapeSpace,
                               boolean escapeUnicode) {
        int len = theString.length();
        int bufLen = len * 2;
        if (bufLen < 0) {
            bufLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        StringBuffer outBuffer = new StringBuffer(bufLen);

        for(int x=0; x<len; x++) {
            char aChar = theString.charAt(x);
            // Handle common case first, selecting largest block that
            // avoids the specials below
            if ((aChar > 61) && (aChar < 127)) {
                if (aChar == '\\') {
                    outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('\\');
                    continue;
                }
                outBuffer.append(aChar);
                continue;
            }
            switch(aChar) {
                case ' ':
                    if (x == 0 || escapeSpace)
                        outBuffer.append('\\');
                    outBuffer.append(' ');
                    break;
                case '\t':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('t');
                          break;
                case '\n':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('n');
                          break;
                case '\r':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('r');
                          break;
                case '\f':outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append('f');
                          break;
                case '=': // Fall through
                case ':': // Fall through
                case '#': // Fall through
                case '!':
                    outBuffer.append('\\'); outBuffer.append(aChar);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (((aChar < 0x0020) || (aChar > 0x007e)) & escapeUnicode ) {
                        outBuffer.append('\\');
                        outBuffer.append('u');
                        outBuffer.append(toHex((aChar >> 12) & 0xF));
                        outBuffer.append(toHex((aChar >>  8) & 0xF));
                        outBuffer.append(toHex((aChar >>  4) & 0xF));
                        outBuffer.append(toHex( aChar        & 0xF));
                    } else {
                        outBuffer.append(aChar);
                    }
            }
        }
        return outBuffer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Why looking into a source code, when there is a [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store-java.io.Writer-java.lang.String-) explaining what will be done, regardless of how it’s implemented…